# Suddenly, domain name can not be resolved - What happened?

Tags: domain-name-system, hostname

My domain is buycott.com

When I run `ping buycott.com` in the command line, it's timing out. It's been working fine for over a year, and suddenly I'm seeing these timeouts of nowhere?

When I use most DNS lookup sites, they're able to resolve it. When I try to access buycott.com on Chrome on my Mac it works, but when I try on LTE on my phone, it doesn't resolve.

This is driving me nuts! What could be happening here?

Answer (score 7):

The delegation points to these nameservers:

```
buycott.com.            172800  IN      NS      ns-178.awsdns-22.com.
buycott.com.            172800  IN      NS      ns-591.awsdns-09.net.
buycott.com.            172800  IN      NS      ns-1381.awsdns-44.org.
buycott.com.            172800  IN      NS      ns-2015.awsdns-59.co.uk.
```

But those servers claim that the nameservers are:

```
buycott.com.            172800  IN      NS      jeff.ns.cloudflare.com.
buycott.com.            172800  IN      NS      lisa.ns.cloudflare.com.
```

You'll want to decide which nameservers you actually do want to use and change the delegation (through your registrar) and/or the authoritative records (in the zone on the nameservers the delegation refers to) to all refer to the correct nameservers.

Ie, the `NS` records in the delegation and the authoritative records must agree.

Comment: Thanks for this! But this has been the setup for over a year and everything was working fine until yesterday. I understand that could be a problem and I will fix it, but I'm really interested in getting to the bottom of why the domain isn't resolving properly all of the sudden. Any thoughts?

Comment: Also, what do you mean "the delegation points to these nameservers"?

Comment: I meant that the `NS` records returned in the authority response by the nameservers for the parent zone (`NS` records which you set up through your registrar) refer to those nameservers.  This kind of inconsistency is a serious problem; whether you personally have noticed it until now or not. It has been in an inconsistent state for as long as things have been set up this way.

Comment: I fixed it right after reading your suggestion. Looks like it's been updated pretty broadly, but I'm still experiencing the issue in the OP. My domain appears to be resolving to `184.73.247.69`, but when I try `ping 184.73.247.69` I get a request timeout? Is this any clue to where the problem might be lying? It's not at the server level, because I can connect to all the servers directly on my mobile devices, but not to buycott.com

Comment: `Is this any clue to where the problem might be lying?` No, that just means it doesn't respond to ping requests. All the above comment means is that the dns via your phone doesn't resolve - which isn't a surprise if previously there was a namesever listed that gave an authorative "that domain doesn't exist" answer - which both the cloudflare namesevers do.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the ping timeout, it looks like buycott.com is resolving just fine on my PC, and I can connect on port 80 via a web browser. As you've stated however, a ping times out. I would suggest this is more likely to be a firewall issue server side. You appear to be using AWS and the IP address appears to be dynamic (I've seen at least 3 different IP addresses since looking at this), are you sure it's setup to respond to ping requests?

Regarding the access from your phone on 4G, I'm having the same issue here. Would guess that the DNS servers in use do not for whatever reason have the records related to your domain. It could well be related to the problem Hakan Lindqvist posted. If you've corrected this now then I'd wait 48 hours (the TTL on the NS records) and then try again.